# Associate an input html element to a color picker dynamically

Tags: javascript, color-picker, dynamically-generated

I'm using [Izzy Color Picker](http://www.izzywebsite.com/tools/jquery-color-picker). 
In order to associate a input with izzy color picker I just have to set the class attribute of the input element to `izzyColor` and the input's id have to be unique.
With javascript I create an input dinamically when I press a boton.

```
n = n+1;
id = "txtColor" + n;
input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("class","izzyColor");
input.setAttribute("id",id);
```

Then, I append the input to a `td` element in an table, but the little image that appears next to the associated input element doesn't appear.
It seems that the problem is only when I create the input with javascript, because if I create the input element with html, it works fine.

When I inspect the html input element created with javascript through the source code, all attributes are set up correctly.

Comment: Just an opinion here: I looked at the code for the plugin and its pretty crappy. If it works for you then great, but I'd go with something else. The fact that they don't provide an easy way to invoke the plugin on a new set of elements is pretty weak. Just my two cents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source, it looks like you might be able to just call:

```
izzyColor();
```

It looks like its not namespaced at all. They define it as `this.izzyColor = function(){...}`, but at that point, I'm pretty sure `this` is just the window.

I'm not sure what that's going to do to existing inputs. You might need to do this:

```
$('input.izzyColor').removeClass('izzyColor').addClass('izzyExisting');
izzyColor();
$('input.izzyExisting').removeClass('izzyExisting').addClass('izzyColor');
```

Let me know how it goes and we can work from there.

Comment: It works, I just had to call `izzyColor()` after  `input.setAttribute("id",id);`, thanks!